# Can't create a TPU node/VM since March 4

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

Since some time around March 4, suddenly I have not been able to create a Cloud TPU node.

When I attempt to create a TPU node/VM via GUI, it crashes upon choosing TPU type with any region. I get tons of JS errors in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CP-CLOUD-TPU-V3')
m=b:90 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CP-CLOUD-TPU-V3')
m=b:90 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CP-CLOUD-TPU-V3')
m=b:90 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CP-CLOUD-TPU-V3')
m=b:90 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CP-CLOUD-TPU-V3')
```

Attempting to create a TPU VM from Cloud Shell results in error code 13 with combinations of any zone or version:

```
gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm create testnode --zone us-central1-a --accelerator-type='v3-8' --version='v2-alpha' --scopes='cloud-platform'
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.compute.tpus.tpu-vm.create) {
  "code": 13,
  "message": "an internal error has occurred"
}
```

What I tested:

1. Attempting the same procedure with a different project - same
   behavior and error.
2. Attempting the same procedure with a new account that never used Cloud TPU before - same behavior and error.
3. Using Chrome from an Android phone with mobile network - same behavior and error.
4. Quotas are fine.

I figured google-cloud-tpu 1.3.2 was released March 8, but I am not sure if that is related to the issue I am getting.

Other parts of GCP, such as VM instances or Cloud Storage work fine - just TPU has been down for me.

Comment: Still no luck.

Verbose debug output did not help neither - all API calls are returning 200. If anything, it feels like the API is failing to fetch pricing information.

Anybody else having the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm create testnode 
   --zone us-central1-a --accelerator-type='v3-8' --version='v2-alpha' 
   --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

The short form --scopes='cloud-platform' is not supported for tpus.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a TPU VM via Cloud Console by using --service-account instead of --scopes.

The GUI still crashes, but you can somehow create a node by repeatedly clicking at preemptible checkbox. I think the possible cause is that they removed scopes from TPU VM and something in their backend now is incompatible with the current GUI code.

Comment: I had the same issue, specifying my service account on the command line like so allowed me to create the tpu:

`gcloud compute tpus tpu-vm create {yournodename} 
--zone=us-central1-f 
--preemptible 
--service-account={yourserviceaccoutnnamehere}@{yourprojectname}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
--version=tpu-vm-tf-2.8.0`